# React event listener and remounting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

Hello I have been learning React since the last week and I resolved a problem  but I am trying to understand why it solved my problem.

Here is the code example :

```
export default class ExampleComponent extends Component{

    constructor(...arg){
        super(...arg);
        this.goToNextPage = this.goToNextPage.bind(this);
        this.state = { currentPage: 1, 
                       chapterImages: []};
    }

    goToNextPage(){
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          currentPage: R.inc(this.state.currentPage)
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (<button onClick={this.goToNextPage}>next</button>)
    }
}
```

I have something that looks like that. In my real code I'm making an ajax call and this is the reason for my component unmount and remount ... Finally, when I click on my button, I get the following error :

```
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component.
This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component.
This is a no-op.
```

But if i drop this line from the constructor :

```
this.goToNextPage = this.goToNextPage.bind(this);
```

And modify the line in the render method to this :

```
return (<button onClick={this.goToNextPage.bind(this)}>next</button>)
```

It's works perfectly but I don't know why I get the error above.

I went that route because when my component is unmounted, it keeps a reference of the binded method "goToNextPage" in the button click listener.

How can I resolve that problem by keeping the bind in the constructor ?

Comment: What's the reason for the component being unmounted? perhaps a more true to life code example might be useful. btw, there's no need to clone the state when using `setState()`, only pass the keys that require update.

Comment: You are somehow unmounting that component after onClick is called, most probably related to some code outside the component itself. I see it's a button, is it in a form that is submitted on click?

Comment: The reason of why my component is unmounted is because when i'm making an ajax call i show a loading icon in the top level of the tree component and so it unmount my component which is in a lower level of the tree component i guess it is the reason of why my component is unmouted and remounted. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Erf i fixed the problem of unmounting my component is no longer unmounting but i still have the same problem i'll post my real code ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my real code class :

```
export default class MangaChapter extends Component{

  constructor(...arg){
    super(...arg);
    this._getPageId = R.prop('pageId');
    this._getPages = R.prop('pages');
    this._generatePageMenuItem = (pageId) => (<MenuItem key={pageId} value={pageId} primaryText={`${pageId}`} />);
    this._pageToMenuItem = R.compose(this._generatePageMenuItem, this._getPageId);
    this._getMangaPageMenuItems = R.compose(R.map(this._pageToMenuItem), this._getPages);
    this._toImageNode = (chapterPage) => (<img src={chapterPage.url} style={{display: 'block', margin: '0 auto'}}/>)
    this._preloadImage = (chapterPage) => new Image().src = chapterPage.url;
    this._preloadImages = R.forEach(this._preloadImage);
    this._getImagePage = R.compose(R.map(this._toImageNode), this._preloadImages, this._getPages);
    this.state = { currentPage: 1, chapterImages: this._getImagePage(this.props.chapter) };
    this.goToPreviousPage = this.goToPreviousPage.bind(this);
    this.goToNextPage = this.goToNextPage.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.getChapter(this.props.params.mangaId, this.props.params.chapterNum);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    console.log('UNMOUNT');
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    const { chapter } = nextProps;
    this.state = { currentPage: 1, chapterImages: this._getImagePage(chapter) };
  }

  handleChange(event, index, currentPage){
    this.setState({currentPage});
  };

  goToPreviousPage(){
    this.setState({
      currentPage: R.dec(this.state.currentPage)
    });
  }

  goToNextPage(){
    this.setState({
      currentPage: R.inc(this.state.currentPage)
    });
  }

  displayPage(){
    return this.state.chapterImages[R.dec(this.state.currentPage)]
  }

  componentDidMount(){

  }

  render(){
    const { chapter, loading } = this.props;
    const chapterName = chapter.name;
    const chapterNum = this.props.params.chapterNum;

    if(loading) return (<CircularProgress size={80} thickness={5} style={loadingStyle} />);

    return (
      <div>
        <h2 style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Chapter { chapterNum } : { chapterName } </h2>
        <div>
          {this.displayPage()}
        </div>
        <div>
        <br/>
          <Row  style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
            <Col sm={4}>
              <RaisedButton
                label="Previous"
                primary={true}
                icon={<ChevronLeft />}
                onClick={this.goToPreviousPage}
              />
            </Col>
            <Col sm={4}>
              Page
              <SelectField
                value={""}
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                style={{width: '80px', display: 'inline-block'}}
                value={this.state.currentPage}
              >
                {this._getMangaPageMenuItems(chapter)}
              </SelectField>
              of { chapter.pages.length }
            </Col >
            <Col sm={4}>
              <RaisedButton
                labelPosition="before"
                label="Next"
                primary={true}
                icon={<ChevronRight />}
                style = {{display: 'inline-block'}}
                onClick={this.goToNextPage}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is for these two method in the constructor :

```
    this.goToPreviousPage = this.goToPreviousPage.bind(this);
    this.goToNextPage = this.goToNextPage.bind(this);
```

If i do that i get the error like above bu if i put these method in the componentDidMount method like that :

```
  componentDidMount(){
    this.goToPreviousPage = this.goToPreviousPage.bind(this);
    this.goToNextPage = this.goToNextPage.bind(this);
  }
```

It works perfectly, do you know why ?